# Custom section numbering in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sections, toctree

I would like to have different numbering for Sphinx:

- `i, ii, iii` for the frontmatter
- `1.`, `1.1`, `2.` for the main content
- `A.`, `B.`, ... for the appendix

The numbering comes from the `:numbered:` option in a `.. toctree::` directive. This is somehow related to the `assign_section_numbers` method on `toctree.py`.

The idea would be to add the option `:format: upper-letters`

I saw that if I add to `_walk_toc` a naive function:

```
def _to_alpha(numstack):
    return [string.ascii_uppercase[i] for i un numstack]
```

I can change the numbering for pages, but not for toctrees.

Also sphink does not seem to be extensible. How would I manage to extend the `TocTreeCollector` class?

Comment: Use custom CSS to change the numbering, or force it with the desired [enumerated list format](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#enumerated-lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add an `appendix` directive to use alpha numbering for sections:

```
""" Rename section number with alphabetic letters for ``.. appendix``
"""
import string
from docutils import nodes
from sphinx.environment.collectors.toctree import TocTreeCollector
from sphinx.directives import TocTree
from sphinx import addnodes
from typing import cast


def alphabize(n):
    """Convert a number to a alphabet number (such as Excel columns)."""
    out = ""
    while n > 0:
        n, remainder = divmod(n - 1, len(string.ascii_uppercase))
        out = string.ascii_uppercase[remainder] + out
    return out


def to_letter(secnum):
    if not secnum or len(secnum) == 0:
        return secnum

    secnum = list(secnum)
    return tuple([alphabize(secnum[0])] + secnum[1:])


class AppendixDirective(TocTree):
    def run(self):
        ret = super().run()
        ret[0][0]['appendix'] = True
        return ret


class Collector(TocTreeCollector):
    def parse_tree(self, env):
        def _walk_toc(node, titlenode, appendix=False):
            for subnode in node.children:
                if isinstance(subnode, (nodes.bullet_list, nodes.list_item, addnodes.only)):
                    _walk_toc(subnode, titlenode, appendix)
                elif isinstance(subnode, addnodes.compact_paragraph) and appendix:
                    reference = cast(nodes.reference, subnode[0])
                    reference['secnumber'] = to_letter(reference['secnumber'])
                elif isinstance(subnode, addnodes.toctree):
                    _walk_toctree(subnode)

        def _walk_toctree(toctreenode: addnodes.toctree, appendix=False) -> None:
            for (_, ref) in toctreenode['entries']:
                if ref in env.tocs:
                    _walk_toc(env.tocs[ref], env.titles.get(ref), appendix)

                    if appendix:
                        env.toc_secnumbers[ref] = {k: to_letter(v)
                            for k, v in env.toc_secnumbers[ref].items()}

        for docname in env.numbered_toctrees:
            doctree = env.get_doctree(docname)
            for toctreenode in doctree.traverse(addnodes.toctree):
                appendix = toctreenode.get('appendix', False)
                _walk_toctree(toctreenode, appendix)

    def assign_section_numbers(self, env):
        rewrite_needed = super().assign_section_numbers(env)
        self.parse_tree(env)
        return rewrite_needed

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('appendix', AppendixDirective)
    app.add_env_collector(Collector)

    return {
        'version': '0.1',
        'parallel_read_safe': True,
        'parallel_write_safe': True,
    }
```

Comment: What do you do with these functions once they are declared ?

Comment: This is an extension code for sphinx. you put this file into the extension folder and add it in your configuration file.

Comment: Before I try to learn what the extension folder is, could you explain in more details what your code does ? Does it only affect the toctrees, or also the way the headers are displayed in the specific pages ? I'm trying to get the "cool" header be displayed as "Article 1 - cool" in the page itself, so I don't know if starting from your system would help me or not